# Tree class implementation with node and leaf

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, tree

```
tree = Node ("one",
             Node ("two", Leaf ("three"), Leaf ("four")),
             Node ("five", Leaf ("six"), Leaf ("seven")))
```

Trying to declare a Tree class with 2 subclasses Node and Leaf to handle the tree object

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

# some functions
#def inorder(self, visitor):
#    Node.inorder(self.left, visitor)
#    visitor(self.data)
#    Node.inorder(self.right, visitor)

#def fns(tree):
#    return

class Node (Tree):
    def __init__(self, value, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.value = value

class Leaf (Tree):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

Would this be the correct implementation?

Comment: For a binary tree, yes.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a correct implementation of binary tree. But keep in mind one thing, if you ever change root of the tree you will need to update every single node and leaf in that tree.

`self.root` is a bad idea in case you would create subtrees which you would later add to another tree. But if you are not planning to do something like this this would be a good idea.